# How can i get metrics from github

Tags: github, github-api

i want to get some metrics from GitHub in order to present it in the Elastic Search

1. how many PR's / branches were created for the last 24 hours
2. how many PR's / branches were merged for the last 24 hours
3. who created most pr's last X days
4. who merged most pr's last X days
5. how long took to merge a PR in the last X days

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/metrics ?

Comment: Be careful of what actions you take based on #3 and #4. I might spend a few days working on a PR with multiple changes, but if I get a gold star for having more PRs, I could easily convert that 1 PR into 10 little ones.